# Vertical scrollbar overlay round-bordered select with CSS

Tags: css, select, scrollbar, overlay

I have one multiple select with some options inside.

```css
select {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #c4c7cc;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #323232;
 width: 100%;
 transition: border-color 0.25s ease;
 font-size: 12px;
}

select:not([disabled]):hover,
select:not([disabled]):focus {
 border-color: #ff7900;
}

select[disabled] {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select multiple class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My preference is to use default scrollbar and always show vertical scrollbar. But my select has border-radius so when running, the vertical scrollbar hides select's top-right and bottom-right corner.

This works well in IE11 because there is enough space in IE11 for the scrollbar not hiding the corners. But in Chrome, it overlays.

I have tried ::-webkit-scrollbar but it always ask me to use customized scrollbar, which I don't want.

So the question is how to make space in select between scrollbar and the border?

https://jsfiddle.net/x2eqqhqy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set border to the parent div instead of `select` and get the result below.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #c4c7cc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: border-color 0.25s ease;
}


select {
  height: 200px;
  border:none;
  color: #323232;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

div:hover{
  border-color: #ff7900;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select multiple class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, I just found this solution. Totally agree. Thanks

Comment: không có chi bạn :v

Answer (score 2):

To hide the corners you must set `border-radius` on parent, with `overflow:hidden`. Don't set `height` on parent. In short, `<select>` elements are difficult to style cross-browser. Every single select/dropdown library hides the `<select>` and draws a surrogate using easier to style elements (typically divs and spans) and than copies the selection to the hidden `<select>`, using JavasScript.

Here's the closest to what you want, without using a plugin:

```css
select {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #323232;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

select[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #c4c7cc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: border-color 0.25s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:hover,
div:active {
  border-color: #ff7900;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select multiple class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: this is another good idea because I don't need to change much work in my project. I'll ask tester if they agree with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apply same border-radius to parent and give `overflow: hidden` like this:

```
div {
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
select {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. But I found 2 good answers above. you can take a look at them :)